# Cant crop image from camera

Tags: android, camera, crop

First of all - im sorry for my bad english. 
I try to get crop from camera photo.

This is my openCamera method:

```
private void openCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
    // ******** code for crop image
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

    try {

        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Do nothing for now
    }
}
```

And here is ActivityForResult:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            }
        }
    }
```

But its crashing with ...

```
03-28 14:40:41.791 15198-15198/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3050)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=file:///data/data/com.android.camera/files/crop-temp (has extras) }
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
                                                   at
```

Absolutely no idea...

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Sorry but youre not right. This Intent works.
I resolve it by - https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");     
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");    
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");    
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);    
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);    
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);    
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);    
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

and `OnActivityResult()` method
`Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
//get the cropped bitmap
Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");`

Comment: what was the issue..?

Comment: Im not sure, but your answer was close for a correct, Abhishek. 
Looks like we must get photo by intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, and only AFTER it use intent com.android.camera.action.CROP with url of photo. Thanks for your answer again)

Comment: please refer this
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

Comment: I try this but its not working for me. Im already resolve it by https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop :)     Very simple and nice)